Simple condition for essential spectrum of self adjoint operator
I am given a bounded self adjoint operator $H:\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ and I was wondering  whether the following condition implies existence of the essential spectrum. The condition is that there exist an orthonormal sequence $\{ \phi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathcal{H} $ such that $\Vert H\psi_n\Vert \in [a,b]$ for all $n$ and I think it implies that $\sigma_{ess}(H)\cap [a,b]\neq \emptyset$. Edit: I also assume that $\langle H\phi_n,\phi_n \rangle >0$ for all $n$.
I was wondering whether the implication is true? This seems like it should follow from Weyl's criterion for essential spectrum, but I'm confused right now how to show it.
My idea/intuition is as follows.
I thought that taking the operator of $E_{[a,b]}=\chi_{[a,b]}(H)$, we should have that $\dim \big( E_{[a,b]} \big)=\infty$. The projection being onto infinite dimensional implies that there is essential spectrum in $[a,b]$.

Did you mean $\langle \phi_n, H\phi_n \rangle \in [a, b]$ instead? Otherwise you could easily have $H = -aI$. Then $E_{[a, b]}(H) = 0$.

@DavidGao I can also assume that $\langle \phi_n, H\phi_n\rangle \in [a,b]$. But I'm pretty sure that $\langle \phi_n, H\phi_n\rangle \in [a,b]$ is not enough. I saw that the numerical range of an operator is convex, which should mean that Rayleigh quotient doesn't give enough information.

I suppose that’s true, even if $\langle \phi_n, H\phi_n \rangle \in [a, b]$ you could still easily have $E_{[a, b]}(H) = 0$. (In any case, any bounded self-adjoint operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space has a nonempty essential spectrum, so if that’s all you want you don’t need any of these.)

I am actually trying to simplify an argument for concluding that $\sigma_{ess}(H)\cap [a,\infty)\neq \emptyset$ for some $a>0$.

Nvm, I thought I found a counterexample, but I realized it is actually true that $\langle \phi_n, H\phi_n \rangle \in [a, \infty)$ implies $[a - \epsilon, \infty)$ intersects with the essential spectrum nontrivially for any $\epsilon > 0$. I assume that is enough for your purpose?

(I suppose that already implies $[a, \infty)$ intersects with the essential spectrum nontrivially. I didn’t need to mention $\epsilon$ in the first place.)

@DavidGao Could you write it explicitly as an answer? I had trouble proving that $\dim(E_{[a,\infty))$.

Suppose there exists an orthonormal sequence $\phi_n$ (or, more generally, a sequence of unit vectors weakly converging to $0$ would be enough) s.t. $\langle \phi_n, H \phi_n \rangle \geq a$ for all $n$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, we shall show that $\dim(E_{[a - \epsilon, \infty)}(H)) = \infty$.
Indeed, assume to the contrary that $\dim(E_{[a - \epsilon, \infty)}(H)) < \infty$. Let $P = E_{[a - \epsilon, \infty)}(H)$. Then $I - P = E_{(-\infty, a - \epsilon)}(H)$. As $\phi_n \to 0$ weakly and $P$ is a finite-dimensional projection, we have $P\phi_n \to 0$ in norm. In particular, for large enough $n$, $\|P\phi_n\|^2 < \frac{\epsilon}{\|H\|}$. Thus, for large enough $n$,
$$\begin{split}
a &\leq \langle \phi_n, H\phi_n \rangle\\
&= \langle P\phi_n, HP\phi_n \rangle + \langle (I - P)\phi_n, H(I - P)\phi_n \rangle\\
&< \epsilon + (a - \epsilon)\|(I - P)\phi_n\|^2\\
&\leq \epsilon + a - \epsilon\\
&= a
\end{split}$$
Which is a contradiction. Thus, $\dim(E_{[a - \epsilon, \infty)}(H)) = \infty$, so $\sigma_{ess}(H) \cap [a - \epsilon, \infty) \neq \varnothing$. Since $\sigma_{ess}(H)$ is closed and $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, this implies $\sigma_{ess}(H) \cap [a, \infty) \neq \varnothing$.
